# Adding a plugin to vite

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, prismic.io, vite

I am trying out Vite and using it to develop a Vue app with Prismic Cms. In reading Prismic Doc's I see have to install dependencies

```
npm install @prismicio/vue @prismicio/client prismic-dom
```

Doc's then say you have to register it:

```
To use @prismicio/vue, you must register it in your app entry point, which is most likely ~/src/main.js.

The access token and API options are only necessary if your repo is set to private.
```

```js
// `~/src/main.js`

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import PrismicVue from '@prismicio/vue'
import linkResolver from './link-resolver' // Update this path if necessary

const accessToken = '' // Leave empty if your repo is public
const endpoint = 'https://your-repo-name.cdn.prismic.io/api/v2' // Use your repo name

// Register plugin
Vue.use(PrismicVue, {
  endpoint,
  apiOptions: { accessToken },
  linkResolver
})
```

In reading Vite doc's I see you add plugins via the vite.config.js file instead of using *Vue.use()* in main.js. So I created one as follows:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import Vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import PrismicVue from "@prismicio/vue";
import linkResolver from "./link-resolver"; // Update this path if necessary

const accessToken = ""; // Leave empty if your repo is public
const endpoint = "https://*******-****.cdn.prismic.io/api/v2"; // Use your repo name

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    Vue(),
    PrismicVue({
      endpoint,
      apiOptions: { accessToken },
      linkResolver,
    }),
  ],
});
```

However I get error as follows:

```
failed to load config from C:\Users\akill\Github\shs\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
TypeError: (0 , import_vue.default) is not a function    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\akill\Github\shs\vite.config.js:53:28)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] 
(C:\Users\akill\Github\shs\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-98dbe93b.js:76005:20)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at loadConfigFromBundledFile (C:\Users\akill\Github\shs\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-98dbe93b.js:76013:17)
    at loadConfigFromFile (C:\Users\akill\Github\shs\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-98dbe93b.js:75932:32)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! shs@0.0.0 dev: `vite --open`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the shs@0.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I also notice VS Code is giving me a hint @ import of PrismicVue line of

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '@prismicio/vue'. 'c:/Users/akill/Github/shs/node_modules/@prismicio/vue/dist/prismic-vue.common.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I have isolated it to the line "PrismicVue({endpoint,apiOptions: { accessToken }, Etc....})," causing the error. Can someone explain what is the proper way to import this plugin in Vite? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`vite.config.js`'s `plugins` property is intended for [Vite plugins](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html), which  are for Vite itself (e.g., adding a custom transform for specific file types). That config is not for [Vue plugins](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html#plugins), which can only be installed in a Vue 3 app with [`app.use()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#use).

To setup Prismic with Vue 3:

1. Install the following dependencies. The `alpha` versions of `@prismicio/vue` and `@prismicio/client` (3.x and 6.x, respectively) are needed for Vue 3 support.

   ```sh
   npm i -S @prismicio/vue@alpha @prismicio/client@alpha prismic-dom
   ```
2. Create a link resolver that returns a route path based on a given Prismic document type. The resolved route path should already be registered in `router.js`:

   ```js
   const resolver = doc => {
     if (doc.isBroken) {
       return '/not-found'
     }

     if (doc.type === 'blog_home') {
       return '/blog'
     } else if (doc.type === 'post') {
       return '/blog/' + doc.uid
     }

     return '/not-found'
   }

   export default resolver
   ```
3. In `src/main.js`, use [`createPrismic()` from `@prismic/vue`](https://github.com/prismicio/prismic-vue/issues/46) to create the Vue plugin, and pass that along with the link resolver to `app.use()`:

   ```js
   import { createApp } from 'vue'
   import { createPrismic } from '@prismicio/vue'
   import linkResolver from './prismic/link-resolver'
   import App from './App.vue'
   import router from './router'

   createApp(App)
     .use(router)
     .use(createPrismic({
       endpoint: 'https://blog-demo2.prismic.io/api/v2',
       linkResolver,
     }))
     .mount('#app')
   ```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-vue3-prismic-js-blog-demo?file=src%2Fmain.js)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a mess in your `setup / package.json` as there is nothing special to do - I bet that you are missing `vite-plugin-vue2` and `vue-template-compiler`.
To get it working, try to create a new project with the following :

`vite.config.js`:

```js
const { createVuePlugin } = require('vite-plugin-vue2');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    createVuePlugin()
  ]
};
```

`main.js`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import PrismicVue from "@prismicio/vue";

const accessToken = ""; // Leave empty if your repo is public
const endpoint = "https://*******-****.cdn.prismic.io/api/v2"; // Use your repo name

Vue.use(PrismicVue, {
  endpoint: endpoint
});

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

`App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img
      alt="Vue logo"
      src="./assets/logo.png"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<style>
#app {
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

then `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "vue2-prismic",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prismicio/client": "^5.1.0",
    "@prismicio/vue": "^2.0.11",
    "prismic-dom": "^2.2.6",
    "vite-plugin-vue2": "^1.4.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^2.0.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have specified I'm using Vue 3. Getting an error on Dev startup of"Vue packages version mismatch: 

- vue@3.2.8 (C:\Users\akill\Github\shs-site\node_modules\vue\index.js)
- vue-template-compiler@2.6.14 (C:\Users\akill\Github\shs-site\node_modules\vue-template-compiler\package.json)" which I assume is because of Vue 3.